# Allowing more than one argument in a string [Go]

Tags: go

I'm using Gomail to grab data from a form and email it to myself. If I wanted to get the users full name, this is what I would use:

```
m.SetBody("text/html", fmt.Sprintf("<b>Full Name</b>: %s", msg.completeName))
```

It something like this in the email:

**Full Name**: John Michael Smith

Now if I wanted to add a message field to the code

```
m.SetBody("text/html", fmt.Sprintf("<b>Full Name</b>: %s", msg.completeName, "<br> <b>Message</b> %s", msg.Content))
```

It outputs this:

**Full Name**: John Michael Smith%!(EXTRA string=

**Message**: %s, string=Hi there!.)

I want it to look like this:

**Full Name**: John Michael Smith

**Message**: Hi there!

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the strings?

Comment: @FredMaggiowski Can you give me an example as to how I can do that? Sorry I'm pretty new to Golang.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you're using Sprintf the wrong way.

The `Sprintf` needs a string format as first argument and then all the variables you need to be inserted in the final string.

Thus your code should be:

```
m.SetBody("text/html", fmt.Sprintf("<b>Full Name</b>: %s <br><b>Message</b> %s", msg.completeName, msg.Content))
```

For more informations I suggest you to read the [Sprintf documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf)

*NOTE*: In the comment I said "why don't you concatenate the string?" since you can also do:

```
m.SetBody("text/html", "<b>Full Name</b>: "+ msg.completeName +" <br><b>Message</b> " + msg.Content))
```